# Is there a one-liner for removing whitespace and specific characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have several strings that look like this:

```
" Hello
  (  World
 ) "
```

and I want to change them to simply the `"Hello World"` equivalent.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to multiple lines of code?

Ex something like this:

```
print(myString.remove(' ()\n'))
```

Comment: you may want to remove new line and rest of the character in this case either you go with regex or simple strip method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions will work for you.

```
bad_symbols = '(){}\n' 
s = 'hello () { world \n }'
s = ''.join([x for x in s if x not in bad_symbols])
```

Comment: That returns `'hello   world  '`...I wonder how that is acceptable to @Scarecrow.

Answer (score 4):

Regex and python in union :)

```
import re

string = " Hello  (  World ) "
print((re.sub(r'\W+',' ', string)).strip())
```

EDIT: Made it a one liner ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = """ Hello
...   (  World
...  ) """
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"(?:^[\s()]+|[\s()]+$|[\s()]+\B)", "", s)
'Hello World'
```

However, this approach has risks. Better do it in two lines:

```
>>> s = """ Hello
...   (  )World
... ( ) """
>>> temp = re.sub(r"(?:^[\s()]+|[\s()]+$)", "", s)
>>> temp
'Hello\n  (  )World'
>>> re.sub(r"[\s()]+", " ", temp)
'Hello World'
```